# Android: How can I scan all visible base stations logging their RSSI and cell id?

Tags: android, gsm

I was working on a research which requires me to record GSM/CDMA base stations (all visible at a particular time). I read some work in which people reported that they can scan 5-6 base stations logging their id and RSSI values. I tried to dig in but was just able to scan for the one connected Base Station. I think it is possible but couldn't find any documentation for the same, online. Also there are some apps developed which give GSM map or something, but no idea how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the android telephony manager.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

Checkout the getNeighboringCellInfo() method

The getNeighboringCellInfo() method is dependant on the phone model on some phones it works and on some it doesnt. It seems this an area where you will feel the pain of android fragmentation. I hope it works for you..

Comment: Thanks for the reply....It seems like it doesn't for for my AT & T GSM conxn (Dell Streak)..It is working for Verizon (Samsung Galaxy S) .....